# Map key to middle click (on Win 7)

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, remapping, touchpad

Is there a utility to map a keyboard key to middle-click?

In particular, I'm trying to map the useless Context Menu key to the middle-click on my laptop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This [Auto Hot Key](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script remaps the context menu key to middle-click:

```
AppsKey::MButton
```

Here is the full [List of Keys, Mouse Buttons, and Joystick Controls](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm).

Answer (score 0):

It's actually possible to accomplish this entirely through some registry hacks, without having autohotkey always running on your computer.

1) create middle_click.ahk consisting only of:

```
MouseClick, Middle
```

2) using autohotkey, convert middle_click.ahk to middle_click.exe

3) open regedit and go to

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/software/microsoft/windows/currentversion/explorer/appkey/
```

4) each of the numbers that you see in this registry folder corresponds to the multimedia keys on your keyboard. decide which one of these keys you use the least. I chose #15, which corresponds to the email hotkey (my laptop doesn't even have an email hotkey)

5) edit the registry of whatever # you chose

```
* delete the Association key

* edit > new > string value

* name it "ShellExecute"

* modify its data value to middle_click.exe (you'll need to store the middle_click.exe file somewhere that's available in your PATH environment variable)
```

6) download http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/OS-Enhancements/KeyTweak.shtml

7) using the keytweak gui, map your menu key to the email key

8) restart your computer

9) voila!