# Click the scrollbar of browser by a button in keyboard

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, browser, scrolling, scroll-wheel, scrollbar

In Chrome or Firefox or Microsoft Edge, is there any way to map a keyboard button to "press the scroll bar"? In this way, I could just press a button and move the mouse to achieve the scroll function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve the scroll function by moving the mouse I guess you're referring to the [auto scroll](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/58900/44425) feature. In this case just press the <kbd>middle mouse</kbd> button (which is the scroll wheel in most modern mice, it's clickable) and move the mouse

If you're talking about the thing that happens when you click the mouse in the trough of the scroll bar then it's the same thing you get when you press <kbd>PageUp</kbd>/<kbd>PageDown</kbd> or <kbd>Space</kbd>/<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>

---

## Edit:

To press some button then move the mouse to scroll without autoscrolling use [ScrollAnywhere](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/scroll_anywhere/)

> Scroll page without touching scroll-bar!
>
> Press Middle (Right / Left) mouse button anywhere on the page to scroll just like with scrollbar.
>
> Features also:
>
> - "grab and drag" scrolling
> - customizable scrollbars!
> - the Momentum auto-scroll

The same add-on is also [available for Chrome and other Chromium-based browsers](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/scrollanywhere/jehmdpemhgfgjblpkilmeoafmkhbckhi?hl=en)

See it in action: https://youtu.be/VLv_wAfVO9A

[image: ScrollAnywhere Settings]

Comment: When pressing middle mouse, the speed of scroll varies when the mouse moves away.      Also page up/page down is just like up/down.           When I want to achieve, is exactly like pressing the scrollbar of the browser, that's all.

Comment: @LukAron then there's something wrong with your environment, because PageUp/PageDown never behaves like Up/Down, one moves a page at once and the other moves one or a few lines

Comment: thanks for the clarification, yes, you are correct,  but it still doesn't simulate clicking the scrollbar itself.

Comment: @LukAron please record a video or something to demo what you want. Because on all current platforms Clicking in the scroll bar will scroll one page, unless you're on some odd desktop environments like Gnome where clicking the scroll bar jumps directly to that point

Comment: I don't think there is any need for a demo. The question is well-defined. I want to press a button, and the effect will be the same as press on the scrollbar of a browser.

Comment: @LukAron I think I get what you expect: you want something similar to **click and drag** the thumb of the scroll bar but without clicking on the actual thumb, not *press on the scroll bar*. See my edit

Comment: yeah, exactly,    since I know how to move the mouse myself, if "press on the scroll bar" could be mapped by a keyboard button,     then "click and drag the thumb of the scroll bar but without clicking on the actual thumb" could be achieved.

Comment: ONE PROBLEM LEFT, the addon only supports left-click or right-click or middle-click on the mouse.       I wonder if it could to set to any button on the keyboard.

Comment: @LukAron that can be easily done with [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/54412-assign-keyboard-key-to-middle-mousebutton/) by mapping any key sequence you want to middle click [Emulate middle mouse button with AutoHotKey](https://superuser.com/q/763283/241386), [Map key to middle click](https://superuser.com/q/143581/241386). But what's the point of pressing the keyboard then move hand to the mouse to scroll? Why don't do everything in the mouse instead?

Comment: because my hand is tired of clicking  12 hours a day.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such keyboard shortcut to drag the scrollbar. You only could try to explore some other ways for scrolling.

E.g. see this question:
[Scroll with mouse like smartphone](https://superuser.com/q/1544118/456981)